# Can I eat fish everyday or alternate day?

Tags: nutrition, food-safety, fish

I am planning to eat fish daily,  because I love fish. If I eat like that do I have any chance of developing health issues ? 
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Is it okay to eat fish every day?](http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/news/hsph-in-the-news/is-it-okay-to-eat-fish-every-day/)

Overall, there are few big risk to your health compared to eating beef or some unhealthy meat everyday.

- [Omega 3 fatty acids could be good for heart health](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21676848). It lowers triglycerides and total cholesterol.
- Some large fish such as [tuna, shark and mackerel may have mercury](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3139210/) in them

> Patients at greatest risk of developing MeHg poisoning are those who
>   eat fish often and who prefer higher-mercury seafood varieties such as
>   swordfish or tuna

- There are heart and other health benefits shown from eating it a couple times a week, but the same benefits can be gotten from daily consumption. But not more if you eat more.

**So your biggest health concerns:**

- Mercury: Your increasing your risk of exposure. Mercury has shown to be bad for brain health and etc.
- Omega 3 fatty acids: can be good for your health

[Fish portioning](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Caregiver/Replenish/WhatisaServing/What-is-a-Serving_UCM_301838_Article.jsp#mainContent)